# JOIN in a Cypher Query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

It seems I do not understand OPTIONAL MATCH correctly.

I have a node (t) that always exists. This node (t) can have relations to other nodes (q), (o) - maybe to both or just one of them.

I am trying to catch in one statement something like

"Show me all information for node (t) and if there is a related node (o) then also all of (o) and if there is a node (q) then also for (q) - if one of them is not available show what you have"

I can do one of both qith a match and an optional match like

```
MATCH (t) -- (o) WHERE t.id = "1234" 
OPTIONAL MATCH (t) -- (q) 
RETURN q,t,o
```

I succeed when I have a path between (t) and (o) no matter if I have (q) or not. But I fail when I do not have (o) and though have (q). If I switch and put (q) in the first row and ((o) in the second its just vice versa, I always loose one of them.

How would I need to query to get either both (o),(q) or just one of them no matter which of them are there?

#### EDIT

1. All nodes (t), (o) and (q) have additional labels
2. I didnt put the query in the right way as I thought this doesnt matter, so the query which fails was
   MATCH (o:Label3) -- (t:Label1) WHERE t.id = "1234" 
   OPTIONAL MATCH (q:Label2) -- (t:Label1) 
   RETURN q,t,o

Comment: What distinguishes between `q` and `o`? Are you just trying to get all nodes connected to `t` (if any), or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: (q) and (o) have different labels, sorry, I didnt mentioned that. It seems that starting both paths with (t) instead of having (q) -- (t) and (t)--(o) seems to solve it. The query MATCH (t:label1) -- (q:label2)  WHERE t.id = 1 OPTIONAL MATCH (t:label1) -- (o:label3)  WHERE t.id = 1 return t,q,o work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to get a collection of all nodes connected to `t`:

```
MATCH (t) WHERE t.id = "1234"
OPTIONAL MATCH (t) -- (o)
RETURN t, COLLECT(o) AS others;
```

Comment: Your approach brought me to think again as I was unsure what I have done wrong - then I believe I found it if its that simple. I wroty my query wrong, correct I should have done MATCH (t)--(o) where t.id = 1 OPTIONAL MATCH (t) -- (q) WHERE t.id=1 return t,o,q. This works now, it seems I just had the wrong order, starting both path with (t) is ok now, didnt thought that this would have made a difference. Thanks so much Sam for your example.

Answer (score 1):

> "Show me all information for node (t) and if there is a related node
>   (o) then also all of (o) and if there is a node (q) then also for (q)
>   - if one of them is not available show what you have"

If `o` and `q` have unique ids you can do it with two `OPTIONAL MATH`. This way:

```
MATCH (t) WHERE t.id = "1234"
OPTIONAL MATCH (t) -- (o {id:567})
OPTIONAL MATCH (t) -- (q {id:568}) 
RETURN q,t,o
```

Comment: `o` and `q` will have the same values. Also, the values will be repeated (due to the effect of cartesian products).

Comment: I believe t, o and q have ids and the query posted by @Balael is a simplification of the problem.

Comment: I would recommend putting those details into your answer. Otherwise, it does not make much sense.

Comment: Thanks for your support, unfortunately they haven't known IDs at the moment when the query fires. But otherwise you would have solved the riddle :)

Comment: @Balael try this: `MATCH (t) WHERE t.id = "1234"
OPTIONAL MATCH (t) -- (o)
OPTIONAL MATCH (t) -- (q) 
WHERE q <> o
RETURN q,t,o`